# Django or Python, how to convert postscript to PDF or Image

Tags: python, django, pdf, type-conversion, postscript

I'm running a RHEL7 system as a web server using Django 1.8.2

I'm researching a solution where a PostScript (PS) file can be uploaded by a Django API and is then converted to either a PDF or Image (such as JPG or PNG).

I put Django or Python, since it doesn't matter whether Django handles the conversion, or passes it off to a pure Python script and receives the result back.

I've been looking into Ghostscript, but I'm coming up with this error...

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=test.pdf -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE file.ps 
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Loading NimbusMonL-Regu font from /usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n022003l.pfb... 2849640 1507460 4012484 2498014 1 done.
%%[ Error handled by opdfread.ps : undefined; OffendingCommand: 9!_NGH!_NGH! ]%%
%%[STACK:
--nostringval--
14
%%]%
```

Open to any solutions. Thanks!

===

@KenS
Thanks for pointing out my failure to include an example of the PS file.

[file.ps](http://biocomsoftware.com/file.ps)

Comment: Are you just looking to convert a ps to a pdf file external to python? If this is all you need to do, you could try `ps2pdf` on the command line which converts ps files.

Comment: ps2pdf simply uses Ghostscript to do the conversion, if it doesn't work locally its not likely to work remotely either. They 'might' be using a more recent version of Ghostscript, but the fact that their last news was 2 years ago doesn't fill me with confidence. Nor that they are still describing it as AFPL Ghostscript when in fact it has used the GPL for some years, and its still pointing at the now unused Wisconsin university mirror......

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your (PostScript) file was originally produced by using Ghostscript to convert a PDF to PostScript. It also looks very much like your PostScript file has been corrupted, it is trying to interpret binary (probably image) data as language tokens.

This may possibly have happened as a result of CR/LF translation, but in any event the reason Ghostscript is throwing you an error is because your PostScript program is broken. It doesn't matter what software you try to use on it, it won't work, the program is (most likely irretrievably) broken.

Of course this is speculation, since you have not posted a URL to the PostScript file.

I'd suggest that you try with one of the sample files in the Ghostscript folder, such as tiger or golfer, those are known to work.

You should also consider using a more up to date version of Ghostscript, 9.05 is 3 years old now.